# Sort XMLListCollection for Spark MobileGrid then Take x elements

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, splice

The spark list and grid components must take an iList as the dataprovider.  Instead of providing them with an XML list, we must now use XMLListCollection.  Sorting an XMLListCollection is easy, but when I attempt to then take to first x number of elements, they are returned unsorted.

How can one first sort, then take the first x elements from the XMLListCollection?

Example sort code:

```
var nameSort:Sort = new Sort();
var nameSortField:SortField =  new SortField( sortField, true);
nameSort.fields = [nameSortField];
pDataCollection = new XMLListCollection(filteredData);
pDataCollection.sort = nameSort;
pDataCollection.refresh();
```

The sort is easy now to splice from the first element.

Comment: Try `pDataCollection.createCursor()` - it might give you the elements from the collection in the desired order.

Comment: How are you trying to take the first elements of the XMLListCollection?  I tried doing pDataCollection.toArray().slice(0, x-1), and it creates an Array of the first x elements in sorted order.

Comment: I was just trying to loop them in a foreach and add to a newly created xmllist then convert to xmllistcollection.   From the array can I create an XMLListCollection again?

Comment: Since the result is an Array, you can create an ArrayCollection from it, rather than going back to an XMLListCollection.  They both extend ListCollectionView (and provide the IList and ICollectionView interfaces), so they can both be used as dataProvider for list/grid.  (Odd that for each didn't work - I tried it and got the expected results...)

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong.  I am using the masked collection now. http://dreamingwell.com/examples/flex/scrollableGraph/srcview/